Overstayed Schengen but can I switch to US passport?
So I’m currently in a Schengen country that isn’t italy but I’ve realized I’ve overstayed my Schengen stay (90 days within 180).
I also have a US Passport. When traveling to a new Schengen country could I switch to the US one to essentially restart my 90 days on that passport?
Simultaneously I’ve been recognized as of recent as an Italian citizen but have yet to get a passport.
I have won a long standing case which for which I have the letter stating I’m citizen from the courts as well as a birth certificate
In anyone’s experience would either of these possibilities get me out of any issues with overstaying the 90 (it’s only by a week or so!)

this has been asked so many times. The TL;DR is: immigration rules don't apply to passports, they apply to individuals.

This question is similar to: Can two passports extend 90 day Schengen rule. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can't overstay in Schengen, you're Italian!

Some unsolicited writing feedback: I'd start the question by introducing the background of your situation. You mention "that isn't italy" in the first sentence, I have no idea why. Then you say "I also have a US passport", and I have no idea why you say "also". In addition to what? What's your primary passport? Then you say you have recently been recognized as an Italian citizen – a-ha so that's why you said "isn't italy". And your first-choice non-US passport is probably Italian then. Ah, but then you say you don't have Italian passport. Now I'm so confused I give up and don't read the rest.


When traveling to a new Schengen country could I switch to the US one to essentially restart my 90 days on that passport?

There is no way to "switch" when traveling between Schengen countries.  The only way is to leave and re-enter the Schengen area.  But switching doesn't give you another 90 days because the 90 days applies to individuals.  Otherwise, anyone who was a dual national of two third countries could live in the Schengen area without a residence permit.

I have won a long standing case which for which I have the letter stating I’m citizen from the courts as well as a birth certificate.

That should be enough to keep you out of trouble in most cases, possibly in connection with your third-country passport and an explanation that you have not yet received the Italian passport.  It might be helpful to have a pending application for the Italian passport but most authorities will not pursue the matter that far.  Legally speaking, you are Italian; administrative fines could be levied for failing to register, but you can't be deported for overstaying, and the administrative fines must be similar to the fines imposed on that country's own citizens for failing to register.

In anyone’s experience would either of these possibilities get me out of any issues with overstaying the 90 (it’s only by a week or so!)

It depends on the country, on your movements, and on the specific issue you're trying to get out of -- in other words, on the reason you have come to the attention of the authorities.  If you're leaving the Schengen area, showing the letter and birth certificate along with your third-country passport is very likely to eliminate any trouble, though there may of course be some delay as the officers evaluate the documents.
If you have already applied for an Italian passport, the simplest course of action is probably to stay where you are until you receive it, if possible.  If you can't, you are unlikely to run into much trouble anyway.  If you've been in the same country for more than three months it might be a good idea to go to another one, at least for a few days or weeks, to avoid any registration requirement.

(As WGroleau points out in a comment, even if passports for different countries were counted separately, you'd still need to ensure that you were outside the Schengen area at midnight when you switch, because if you were to leave and re-enter using different passports on the same day, that day would have to count against both 90-day periods.  Day 1 on the second passport would be day 90 on the first.  When you want to switch back to the first, on day 90 under the second passport, that's day 179 on the first passport, for which you have already used up your 90 days, so you would have to wait two days before you could legally be present under that passport.)

showing the letter and birth certificate along with your Schengen passport I am guessing you meant non-EU? With a passport from a Schengen country, the birth certificate and all the rest become unnecessary.

@Relaxed yes, I meant "third country passport" since obviously the premise of the question is not having a Schengen passport to show.  Thanks for bringing the error to my attention.

Since jus sanguinis ("right of blood") in Europe is most often the base of a citizenship claim, I don't see how showing the birth certificate would be of any advantage. Only in countries (predominantly in the  Americas) where Jus soli ("right of soil") is the base of citizenship would the birth certificate have any advantage. In this case the OP has not stated their present citizenship (visa required for the Schengen Area or not) -nor- whether they have a residence permit for Italy.

Only an Italian national ID, that explicity states that they are Italian, or an passport will resolve the OP problem. Until then the letter may help, but not the birth certificate.

@MarkJohnson The OP hasn't really explained what their claim to citizenship is based on but a birth certificate (or several, as the case may be) also documents ancestry obviously. The question also mentions a US passport.

@Relaxed I also recall hearing that Italy issues birth certificates to Italian citizens born outside of Italy, even if that citizenship is established in adulthood, so I assume that this is probably such a certificate.  If that is right, then obviously a recently issued Italian birth certificate is fairly good evidence that Italy has recently confirmed that the person is Italian.

@MarkJohnson I assume that the birth certificate was issued by Italy as part of the procedure establishing Italian nationality.  I recall reading on this site or [Expatriates.SE] some years ago that Italy does this, though I have no more definitive knowledge of the practice.  I further assume that the certificate mentions the Italian nationality explicitly or is otherwise obviously connected to the recent establishment of OP's Italian citizenship.  I have also assumed that the other citizenship is UK or at least commonwealth, so visa exempt.

@phoog And what do you assume that an official, doing a spot check if someone is legaly within the Schengen area, that a birth certificate is suffient to prove that they are not a third country national. I see no presumption for this in the Schengen Border code, nor do you quote any. A lot of 'assumptions' on your part, but no quotations of the legal basis that a official would need to agree with your expressed opinion.

@MarkJohnson It wouldn't be in the Borders Code, which starts with a blanket exemption for people covered by the freedom of movement. And nobody assumes that it wouldn't be easier with a national ID or that it might take some time for the border guards to be convinced and check the OP's citizenship. The answer is just making the completely obvious point that it's better to have as much documentary evidence as possible to buttress the story. You're the one making a lot of assumptions to claim it would be entirely useless.

The legal basis is in directive 2004/38/EC, specifically article 5(4). “Where a Union citizen […] does not have the necessary travel documents or, if required, the necessary visas, the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to […] corroborate or prove by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement and residence.” “Corroborate” in particular is a very weak standard, it doesn't need to be incontrovertible proof, just enough to make it more likely than not.

@MarkJohnson an official has no need to make assumptions about the birth certificate because the official will see it directly: either it will be useful, if my assumptions are correct, or it won't, if they aren't.

nitpick: the hypothetical dual-passport trick also wouldn't work for another reason—the day you switch would count for both.  So if you switch on the 90th and 180th, your switch back would be an immediate 91st day on that passport.

@WGroleau I've added that to my answer since it does help illustrate how days are counted.

@phoog In this Situation, where only after 'a long standing case' the citizenship has been determined, a birth certificate alone will not help to 'corroborate or prove' the EU citizenship for a simple immigration check. Otherwise there would not have been 'a long standing case' if simply showing the birth certificate confinced the court. Either a certified copy of the courts conclusion or an ID/Passport is what the OP requires.

@MarkJohnson once again, what you're saying isn't true if the birth certificate was issued after the conclusion of long standing case as a result of the court's order.  See Working in the EU: I come from USA and I have Italian passport at [Expatriates.SE] for an example of someone who was born outside Italy but has an Italian birth certificate after establishing Italian citizenship by descent as an adult.

If you had different names on the two passports, you might get away with it—but if caught, the hassle might be even worse!


I also have a US Passport. When traveling to a new Schengen country could I switch to the US one to essentially restart my 90 days on that passport?

Since your US passport has no entry stamp, it will automatically be assumed you have overstayed.

Simultaneously I’ve been recognized as of recent as an Italian citizen but have yet to get a passport.

Once you have proof that you are an Italian citizen, nobody will be interested in any overstay caused while you were a third country national.
As an Italian citizen you may be required, after 3 months, to register in the Schengen country you are presently in (depending on the local laws).

But failing to register typically leads to a slap on the wrist, not expulsion. It's much less serious than overstaying.

As a Schengen area citizen you are entitled to travel within Schengen area with your ID only - it proves you are Schengen area citizen after all.
As a Schengen area permanent resident you are obliged to travel with your passport and 90/180 rule apply to you except for the country you are resident of. Your stay in that peculiar country works for your 90/180 reset as your homeland or any-country-out-of-Schengen do.
If you can prove you are Italian citizen, you are okay. If not, you are in trouble. If you try to circumvent the issue you are in more serious trouble.

There is no such thing as "schengen area citizen" or "schengen area permanent resident", the correct terms are very different.

Yes, the corrct terms are different. On the other hand using shorthand reader-friendly words can convey the idea easier than correct terms in legalese.

Not if they mislead and are basically incorrect, for example your term equates the Schengen area with the EU and that is incorrect. Also what about Irish citizens?

@Crowley I've sent an edit which should maintain the clarity while correcting terminology. Do note however that OP is not an EU resident, and if they weren't an Italian citizen none of this answer would apply, expanding it to cover the core question of "can I switch passports to get another 90/180" might be wise.

@ave EU is not Schengen and Schengen is not EU. Switzerland and Norway are members of Schengen area but they are not in the EU. Romania is a member of EU but not Schengen area. You were be in deep sh... trouble as czech crossing accidentaly borders to Austria back in 2000s when Czech Republic was in EU but not in Schengen yet.

@Crowley Correct, but: EU citizens get free movement to all of EU, and Schengen residents get 90/180 to all of Schengen (non-schengen EU countries may also offer visa-free access, like Cyprus, but unlike Ireland). Edit on my comment: Schengen residents get access to schengen, not EU residents. whoops, sucks for the irish residents. changed my edit request.

@Crowley Romania is in the Schengen area; land border checks remain but for every other purpose, including validity of visas and residence permits, it is in the Schengen area.

@ave Your edit also contains many imprecisions: (1) there is no such thing as a Schengen resident, you're only a resident in one specific Schengen member state (2) the Schengen acquis doesn't have any notion of “tourist”, it covers all short stay visits,(3) I cannot see how “permanent” residence (long-term residence?) makes a difference to this Q&A and (4) you left one instance of “Schengen citizen” making the whole thing even more confusing. Consequently, I think it's best to let Crowley edit the answer as they see fit (and vote accordingly).

Incidentally, the notion of a 90/180 “reset” is potentially confusing or misleading. Nothing ever gets reset, it's just that time in your country of residence or, obviously, outside the Schengen area simply doesn't count as time spent in the Schengen area.

@Crowley After 2004, the main impediment to the freedom of movement of Czech citizen wasn't the fact that the country hadn't joined the Schengen area, it was the restrictions under the transition period following the enlargement. Even Austrian citizens were supposed to use a border crossing point and show their ID but neither them nor, e.g., British citizens could conceivably be in (deep) shit for finding themselves in Austria.

@Relaxed I don't object. The shitty situations were exclusive for Czechs in Austria. you know, Temelín, 1918, 1938-1945,... it was like Borat and his neighbour.

@Relaxed (1) "Schengen resident" clearly means "resident in a schengen country", feel free to add a few more words on the post. (2) I'm aware, but almost all short stays are tourism, business travel and family/friend visits (which are all often grouped up to tourism in the eye of travelers), feel free to swap it out for that if you so desire. (3) being a permanent resident of an EU? schengen? country, for example, gets you a visa fee waiver to Republic of Ireland. (4) my bad.

@ave I started doing that but, together with correcting the remaining errors, it would have meant completely rewriting the answer, that's not what edits are for. And if you don't use more accurate terminology, what's the point?

On “permanent” residence, I used scare quotes because that is not a well defined category. What gets you a visa fee waiver in Ireland is simply being a resident, on any long-term visa or residence permit, even for inherently short and transient stays (as long as it's longer than 90 days) but this is completely unrelated to rules for long stays in Italy. Incidentally the OP wouldn't need a visa in Ireland as a US citizen and I suspect they might even be a British citizen so brining this up is completely irrelevant and confusing in this specific Q&A.

@Relaxed as I understand it, in the context of union law, "permanent residence" is indeed well defined and denotes the right one obtains under free movement law after living somewhere for five years.  (Of course, the majority of such people will be EU citizens and have no use for a visa waiver in Ireland.)

@phoog Yes, that's correct but we were talking about third country citizens without any reference to the EU freedom of movement here so it seemed obvious that it didn't apply. Instead, I assumed ave meant either some national status like a Niederlassungserlaubnis, carte de résident, etc., the EU long-term resident status, or maybe simply being a resident, without explaining which.
